# creating variables on loop with different names visual

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I wan't to create a bunch of variables inside a `While`, each one with different names.

Here is what i tried:

```
 Dim asd As Integer = 1
    While asd < 5
        Dim picturebox +asd As New Picturebox
    End While
```

I want that it creates the Picturebox1 Picturebox2 ... and so on, but the "asd" variable won't evaluate and the code won't work. How could you create variables with different names in a loop with Visual Studio?

Comment: Why don't you use an array? `picturebox[3] = new PictureBox()`?

Comment: probably a good idea to add them to a `form.Controls` somewhere rather than just create them en masse.  Its the 21st century, we have robot dogs and flying cars, so no need to use an old fashioned array, use a `List(of PictureBox)` if you need to store them anywhere besides a Controls collection.

Comment: @Plutonix FYI: The items in a `List<T>` are actually stored in an (old fashioned) `Array<T>` Besides that, I totally agree with you;)

Comment: Its worth noting that the name that you give to your variables inside your loop is irrelevant. Once the loop finishes you can't reference the variables by the names you've given them, you would need to find them in whatever collection you added them to in order to do anything with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past is something like:

```
For i = 0 to 5
    Dim t As New PictureBox()
    t.Name = "PictureBox" & i
    Me.Controls.Add(t)
Next
Dim picToChange = From r in Me.Controls Where Typeof(r) Is PictureBox AndAlso r.Name = "PictureBox1" Select r
If picToChange IsNot Nothing AndAlso picToChange.Any Then
    'Do Something
End If
```

This is a very basic example and your `linq` would probably be more dynamic than the one I used but you should get the idea. In this case I'm assuming that you are just putting the `PictureBoxes` on the form, if this isn't the case then you will need to `linq` through whichever collection you are adding the controls to.

Edit #1:

As far as events are concerned you will need to add the handlers manually. So your code would become:

```
For i = 0 to 5
    Dim t As New PictureBox()
    t.Name = "PictureBox" & i
    AddHandler t.Click, AddressOf(FunctionToHandleClick)
    Me.Controls.Add(t)
Next
Dim picToChange = From r in Me.Controls Where Typeof(r) Is PictureBox AndAlso r.Name = "PictureBox1" Select r
If picToChange IsNot Nothing AndAlso picToChange.Any Then
    'Do Something
End If
```

And the FunctionToHandleClick would look like this:

```
Private Sub FunctionToHandleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ClickEventArgs)
End Sub
```

Comment: The code inside the `i` loop can be reduced to one line: `Me.Controls.Add(New PictureBox() With {.Name = "PictureBox" & i})` ;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå very true, I was trying to be as explicit as possible though, since the asker seems new to VB...

Comment: Yeah, I just thought it was worth mentioning;)

Comment: In case that i need a `.click` event on the created picturebox, what im supposed to do? `Handles t.click` gives an error

Comment: @user1938775 Added a second block of code that goes over how to handle the events.

Comment: Its the same thing to handle the click on each of the five picture boxes diferently?

Comment: @user1938775 evaluate `sender` to find out which raised the event

Comment: @Plutonix Okay, but if u can help me a little more, how should i evalate it? i tried  `If sender.ToString = "Picturebox1" Then` but it didn't work, any idea of how should it work?

Comment: @user1938775  sender is going to be the picturebox firing the event.  when you create it give it a good name ("pictureBox1" is NOT) and/or use the .Tag property so that `Ctype(Sender, PictureBox).Name` or .Tag give you the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)?

```
Dim pictureboxes(5) As PictureBox

For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    pictureboxes(i) = New PictureBox()
Next
```

Comment: Edited.  I was being silly and posted it in C# syntax.

Comment: and what if the amount of picture boxes i need to create is a variable too, is it possible? `dim pictureboxes(variable) As Picturebox`